# How do I remove Focus when I mouse-click on QtreeWidget?

Tags: c++, qt, qtreewidget

I give  QTreeWidget->setIndentation(30);
but there is a background Colour on the mouse click.

`QTreeWidget->setFocusPolicy(Qt::NoFocus);`
[image: Picture]
Note: If this is not possible, is there any way to change the background colour to the same as the qtreewidget background?

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of [Remove blue selection from QTreeView in "fusion" style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28366805/remove-blue-selection-from-qtreeview-in-fusion-style) but I'm confused about why you think indentation would remove/cause that background color, it's not related. That color is the item selection color, which can be modified using stylesheets, see this: [Customizing QTreeView](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qtreeview).